# Anyone knows a ruby library that works like Readability?

Tags: javascript, css, ruby, readability

[Readability](http://www.readability.com/) is a javascript program who transform a html page in a more readable one. I'm looking for a Ruby implementation, or something similar, anyone knows a library with this characteristics?

Comment: I added javascript and css tags to the question to expand its visibility to that crowd.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find a Ruby port for arc90 Readability at the following url
https://github.com/cantino/ruby-readability

Comment: This is the simple answers I was looking for